# Does Hive use NULL as a possible value to aggregate by?

Tags: hive, aggregate-functions, aggregate

When I aggregate data in hive, how does the group by statement treat NULL values in the aggregating column?

Say I launch the following query

`select col_a, count(1) from mytable group by col_a ;`

and that `col_a` contains `0`, `1` and `NULL` values. Will the result have 2 rows (0 and 1)
or 3 (0,1 and NULL)?

Comment: Loading some test data into a table and running said query seems like a pretty obvious solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does group by on NULL values and you will get 3 values. Also please modify your query to this:

```
Select col_a, count(1) from mytable group by col_a ;
```